# Error while make on Mac (Mavericks) the 3.0 beta

Tags: c++, makefile, opencv3.0

I need new features on OpenCV 3.0 beta.
The explanation to install it is already here: http://hugofeng.info/2014/04/17/Compile%20OpenCV3.0%20on%20OSX/

When I do `make`, the following error is up:

I'm trying to sort this error but I can't...
http://pastebin.com/DPRdvjvU (I can't paste all the RAW data here).

I've seen similar errors solved because of CUDA or sorting flags, but I didn't get it to work.

do you have any clue? thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there were an error with Viz, so in the guide, not following the VIZ part and compiling as:

> cmake "Unix Makefile" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_viz=OFF ..

instead of

> cmake "Unix Makefile" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF ..

I hope to help to new people who want to try the beta.

I don't know why I got bad reputation on this question.